# Checking uhc and lhc of this correspondence

Tags: general-topology

I'm fairly new to correspondences, so please bear with me.

Let $\phi:R\rightrightarrows R$ be given by
\begin{align}
\phi(x)=\begin{cases}
\{x\},x<0\\
\{0,1\},x=0\\
\{x+1\},x>0
\end{cases}
\end{align}

Here are 4 questions that I need to answer:

1. Is $\phi$ closed valued? Compact valued?
2. Is $\phi$ upper hemi-continuous at $x=0$?
3. Is $\phi$ lower hemi-continuous at $x=0$?
4. Is $\phi$ closed at $x=0$?

Here's my attempt:

1. It is closed valued, since when $x<0,\{x\}$ is closed; when $x=0,\{0,1\}$ is closed; when $x>0,\{x+1\}$ is closed. Thus, for all $x$, $\phi(x)$ is closed; therefore $\phi$ is closed valued. Similarly, since when $x<0,\{x\}$ is compact; when $x=0,\{0,1\}$ is compact; when $x>0,\{x+1\}$ is compact. Thus, for all $x$, $\phi(x)$ is compact; therefore $\phi$ is compact valued.
2. If $\phi$ is uhc at $x_0=0$, then for all open sets $O\subseteq Y$ such that $\phi(0)\subseteq O,$ there exists an open set $U\subseteq X$ with $x_0\in U$ such that $\forall x\in U,\phi(x)\subseteq O$. However, since $\phi(0)=\{0,1\}$, an open set $O$ which includes $\{0,1\}$ doesn't exist. So it's not uhc.
3. Similarly, if $\phi$ is lhc at $x_0=0$, then for every open set $O\subseteq Y$ such that $\phi(x_0)\cap O\neq\varnothing$, there exists an open set $U\subseteq X$ with $x_0\in U$ such that for all $x\in U,\phi(x)\cap O\neq\varnothing$. However, we cannot find an open set $O$ such that $O\subseteq Y$ and $\phi(x_0)\cap O\neq\varnothing$. So $\phi$ is not lhc.
4. By the definition, $\phi$ is closed at $x_0=0$ if for any sequences of pairs $(x_n,y_n)$ with $x_n\to x_0,y_n\to y\in Y$ and $y_n\in\phi(x_n)$, we have $y\in\phi(x_0)$. Take the sequence $x_n=\frac{1}{n}$ and $y_n=2$. However, $2\notin\phi(0)$. Thus, $\phi$ is not closed at 0.

Am I correct? Appreciate any insights.